# SQL plus, top 3 rank across two tables

Tags: sql, oracle, rank, dense-rank

I'm trying to find a way to query the top three users in a database in terms of number of listens and output their user ID and their rank.

The schema for the two tables in question is as follows :

```
User(user_id, email, first_name, last_name, password, created_on, last_sign_in)

PreviouslyPlayed(user_id, track_id, timestamp)
```

I could see how many people pull this off with a count query, but am wondering is there's a way to do this with a rank or dense rank

Comment: Don't name your table User. It's a reserved word in Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the user id and are using Oracle 12g+, then you can do:

```
select pp.user_id, rank() over (order by count(*) desc) as therank
from previouslyplayed pp
group by pp.user_id
order by count(*) desc
fetch first 3 rows only;
```

In earlier versions, you would use a subquery:

```
select pp.*
from (select pp.user_id, rank() over (order by count(*) desc) as therank
      from previouslyplayed pp
      group by pp.user_id
     ) pp
where therank <= 3;
```

You might want to review `row_number()`, `rank()`, and `dense_rank()` to be sure you are getting what you really want (the difference is in how they handle ties).

You only need the `join` if you are concerned that something called `user_id` in one table is not a valid user id.  That seems unlikely, in any well-designed database.